# if value in multidimentional array unset whole contained array

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array, unset, array-multisort

I have a script to add items to a db.

currently I have an array being created like this:

```
foreach(blah as $album){

$add[] = array('album' => $album['name'],
               'test' => $album['test']
            );

} // end foreach
```

the album name is not always unique, and `$album['test']` can be a random text (which is used later) or it can be 'FALSE' (when i say false, I mean, the word false, spelled in text letters)

i need a function to somehow search the array, and compare the names and test values... there could be a few entries for each album name, with a few different random text values, and one saying FALSE. if there is an array entry with the test value set as FALSE, then it will remove all other contained arrays that have the same album name...

so this:

```
array(array('album' => 'album_name1', 'test' => 'xqus8n4n'),
      array('album' => 'album_name1', 'test' => 'FALSE'),
      array('album' => 'album_name1', 'test' => 'jdh4dhdk'),
      array('album' => 'album_name2', 'test' => 'hdis8ebk'),
      array('album' => 'album_name2', 'test' => 'hisb8bs7'),
      array('album' => 'album_name2', 'test' => 'FALSE'),
      array('album' => 'album_name3', 'test' => 'yek98abk'),
      array('album' => 'album_name3', 'test' => '8iksh2q7')
     );
```

becomes this:

```
array(array('album' => 'album_name1', 'test' => 'FALSE'),
      array('album' => 'album_name2', 'test' => 'FALSE'),
      array('album' => 'album_name3', 'test' => 'yek98abk'),
      array('album' => 'album_name3', 'test' => '8iksh2q7')
     );
```

I hope this makes sense, as it can seem a little confusing unless you know my whole script structure, this is why I gave so much info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$multiarray = array(
      array('album' => 'album_name1', 'test' => 'xqus8n4n'),
      array('album' => 'album_name1', 'test' => 'FALSE'),
      array('album' => 'album_name1', 'test' => 'jdh4dhdk'),
      array('album' => 'album_name2', 'test' => 'hdis8ebk'),
      array('album' => 'album_name2', 'test' => 'hisb8bs7'),
      array('album' => 'album_name2', 'test' => 'FALSE'),
      array('album' => 'album_name3', 'test' => 'yek98abk'),
      array('album' => 'album_name3', 'test' => '8iksh2q7')
     );

$keysToRemove = array( );

// Go and find all the FALSE values and which albums they belong to
foreach ( $multiarray as $album ) {
  if ( in_array( 'FALSE', $album ) ) {
    $keysToRemove[] = $album['album'];
  }
}

// Remove all instances of the albums that had FALSE values
// except the ones that had the word FALSE (we keep those :p )
for( $i = 0; $i < count($multiarray); $i++ ) {
    if ( ( in_array( $multiarray[$i]['album'], $keysToRemove ) ) && ( $multiarray[$i]['test'] != 'FALSE' ) ){
        unset( $multiarray[$i] );
    }
}

// reset keys so that they are numerical again.
$multiarray = array_values(array_filter($multiarray)); 

print_r( $multiarray );
```

Gives the following result:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [album] => album_name1 [test] => FALSE ) 
  [1] => Array ( [album] => album_name2 [test] => FALSE ) 
  [2] => Array ( [album] => album_name3 [test] => yek98abk ) 
  [3] => Array ( [album] => album_name3 [test] => 8iksh2q7 ) 
)
```

Comment: this looks promising... but i dont want to remove the albums that didnt have false values, if a false value exists for that array... sorry :)

Comment: Well, try my updated code above, seems to give you the results you want

Answer (score 0):

Use the php function array_key_exists()

```
foreach($album as $alb){

 if (array_key_exists('FALSE', $alb)) {

  // Remove other array keys or save into new array
 }

} // end foreach
```

Comment: i tried that code with echoing $alb where you put save into new array... and got no output at all... that is searching if an array key is called 'FALSE', i need to search the values, and if one of the 'test' values is 'false', then all other arrays with the same album name are unset. much appreciated though

Comment: Yes, sorry, in_array("FALSE",$alb) would do the trick. Then save to an array for removing other nodes later.

Answer (score 0):

this gives the ouput you want

```
  function array_searches($item,$key,$keys,$value){
    if($key[$keys]==$value){
    return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
    $array= array(
          array('album' => 'album_name1', 'test' => 'xqus8n4n'),
          array('album' => 'album_name1', 'test' => 'FALSE'),
          array('album' => 'album_name1', 'test' => 'jdh4dhdk'),
          array('album' => 'album_name2', 'test' => 'hdis8ebk'),
          array('album' => 'album_name2', 'test' => 'hisb8bs7'),
          array('album' => 'album_name2', 'test' => 'FALSE'),
          array('album' => 'album_name3', 'test' => 'FALdsfSE'),
        array('album' => 'album_name3', 'test' => 'FALsdfSE'),
    );

    $i=0;


function custom_op($array){
$new_array=array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
if(array_custom_search($key,$value,'test','FALSE')){
$new_array[]=$value;
foreach($array as $key1=>$value1){
if(array_search($key1,$value1,'album',$value['album'])){
unset($array[$key1]);//unset the array value where 'test' is false 
}
}
}
}


foreach ($new_array as $key=> $value){
$array[]=$value;
}
echo "<pre>asdf";
print_r($array);
}
```